# cannot get related table with Include in edmx and LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, edmx

Now I have 3 tables:

tbl_User: UserID, UserName

tbl_Role: RoleID, RoleName

tbl_UserRole: UserID, RoleID

The relationship is: tbl_User - tbl_UserRole - tbl_Role (1 User for many Role, and 1 Role for many User)

in edmx, I tried to use like this:

```
var users =
    ((from u in DbContext.tbl_User
    join ur in DbContext.tbl_UserRole on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
    join r in DbContext.tbl_Role on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
    select u) as ObjectQuery<tbl_User>).Include("tbl_UserRole").Include("tbl_Role");
```

What I need to get information of tbl_User and RoleName (in tbl_Role).
How can I do that?

Please advise. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how your entities are related?  Perhaps a screenshot of your EDMX designer?

Comment: Hi damienc88, I updated the question again:
"The relationship is: tbl_User - tbl_UserRole - tbl_Role (1 User for many Role, and 1 Role for many User)"
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply just trying to get a users with their roles, can you not just:

```
var users = DbContext.tbl_User.Include("tbl_Role")
```

Without a clearer picture of your entity relationships, I'm going to assume that this will work.  If you were to show the entity classes or a picture of your EDMX designer then a more relevant answer might be posted

**Edit:**
Assuming the above code fetched you your users, you could access the roles as follows:

```
users.First().tbl_role.Select(x => x.RoleName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you see 3 tables ( tbl_User - tbl_UserRole - tbl_Role) and my linQ, you will see how its relationship. It is easy to understand.
With your linQ, how can I access RoleName? please give me one more sample. I'm very appriciated.

Comment: Actually, it's easy to understand, but the exact sample depends on the exact property names in your EDMX.  If your mapping has pluralized relationships, we're not including tbl_Role, but tbl_Roles.